# Communications link failure SSH Tunnel on Datagrip

Tags: ssh, datagrip

I need to connect RDS through SSH for now(Local -> EC2 -> RDS).

So I tried to connect MySQL via SSH Tunnel option on Datagrip, however, It cannot connect to server.

```
[08S01] Communications link failure  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate).
```

I tried MySQL Workbench with `Standard TCP/IP over SSH` option. It works well.

Is that different between `TCP/IP over SSH` and `SSH Tunnel`?

Or Did I something wrong?

[image: MySQL Workbench]

This is my workbench screenshot. It works.

[image: Datagrip2]

[image: Datagrip3]

[image: Datagrip1]

This is my Datagrip screenshot.
I wrote host as RDS endpoint but it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [issue DBE-13313](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13313) and try suggested workarounds, the issue is with disabled TLSv1 protocol:

> #### Workaround #1
>
> We've updated java recently and we've moved to `TLSv1` to the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` due to security reasons. So to get it back you need to do the following:
>
> 1. Create a file `custom.java.security` with the following contents:
>
>    ```
>    jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
>        DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
>        include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
>    ```
>
> I removed `TLSv1` from the list.
>
> 2. Go to you data source *Advanced* tab and add to *VM Options*: `-Djava.security.properties=${PATH_TO_FILE?}/custom.java.security`. Don't forget to replace `${PATH_TO_FILE?}`.
> 3. Restart IDE.
> 4. You can connect.
>
> #### Workaround #2
>
> If you are running MySQL 8.0, 5.7.28, 5.6.46 and later and your server is configured with TLSv1.2 you can enabled it in driver:
> open up data source properties, switch to Advanced tab and set value for `enabledTLSprotocols` to `TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3`
>
> [image]
>
> Due to MySQL bug you can receive error `bad handshake`, that means you can't use TLSv1.2, in this case please disable this option and use workaround #1.
>
> #### Workaround #3
>
> enabledTLSProtocols = TLSv1.1 ( optional )
> VM Options = "-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves"
>
> [image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Mysql 5.7.25 so *Workaround #2* not working and I applied *Workaround #3* only adding `"-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves"` into VM options.

Comment: Workaround #2 worked for me